# How to define message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
             ^ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

anybody knows how to difine message? ask for more code if its necessary. Thanks

Comment: `let message` will create the variable and you'd stop *this* error. Not sure what the value of `message` should be, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message` is a parameter in the `message` event, therefore, I'm assuming you either do not have a `message` event or you have one but you did not place `const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);` inside of it.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like your code is not inside the `message` event

```js
client.on("message", message => {
*code here*
});
```

you need to put `args` variable inside this event.